WSL2 different memory, processor and swap for each instance, running Docker and Ubuntu
i have WSL2 on a windows 11 laptop. Used docker desktop and have installed Ubuntu as a seperate instance.
wsl -l -v

NAME                     STATE           VERSION

docker-desktop           Stopped           2
docker-desktop-data        Stopped           2
Ubuntu                     Running           2


I want to give more memory, swap and processors to the docker-desktop instance.
I tried specifying less in my windows profile .wslconfig and more in dockers
/etc/wsl.conf but they both take what is in the .wslconfig
I'm concerned that if I use Ubuntu, it may take away too many resources from my Docker containers.
How can I tweak these three values per instance?

The short answer is "you can't do that", but if you can provide more details (via [Edit] to the question) then perhaps there are workarounds or other ways to accomplish what you want.  For instance, what is the problem you are experiencing?  Is something in Ubuntu taking up too many resources relative to Docker, or are you just concerned that it will? And docker-desktop-data itself can't possible be a problem, since it doesn't run anything, so why would you need to limit it?

Yes just you just concerned that it will if I use Ubuntu while using docker. I guess I will try for a few days and see what happens. thanks


How can I tweak these three values per instance?

Since all WSL2 distributions run under the same WSL2 virtual machine, it's not possible to tweak those values specifically for each distribution. That's the reason they are controlled from the "VM-level" .wslconfig rather than /etc/wsl.conf.
However, there may be some workarounds for your use-case.
First, just ignore docker-desktop-data since it doesn't actually run anything. As the name suggests, it is simply where the data (images, volumes, etc.) are stored.
With that out of the way, it sounds like you just need to make sure that nothing in the Ubuntu distribution can take too much memory, swap, or CPU away from what's running in Docker. If you have a particular process you are running in Ubuntu that is being problematic, then the best bet is to tackle it specifically.
If you are going to run something that you think might be problematic in Ubuntu, you could:

Limit the max CPU usage by running using the nice command.
Limit the CPU and memory by running it with the prlimit command
Limit the CPU, Memory, and swap by running it in a CGROUP

